# Add some space and border between list items in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In my header, i have some links, and i would like to add some space and a border between them.

I tried adding content with ::before pseudo, but it doesnt put the content to the place i want to.

```css
.header_links_ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header_links_ul li a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .header_links_ul li+li::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    background: #ff0000;
    content: '';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="header_links_ul header_links_ul_left d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-start">
      <li><a href="#">Vásárlási információk</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Szállítás</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="header_links_ul header_links_ul_right d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end">
      <li><a href="#">Regisztráció</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bejelentkezés</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

The result i have now, and what i want, i show it on a photo.
[image: Photo, click here]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add position:relative to the li tags, plus some padding/margin to space them out correctly.
Try this:

```
.header_links_ul li+li {
 position: relative;
 padding-left: 20px;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
```

The ::before pseudo elements are positioned absolutely, so the top and left values you have specified *'will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element itself meaning it will be placed relative to the page itself.'* (which is what's happening in your case).

Citation/further reading:
https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code. Attached [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/munni095/9k34v2bL/5/)

```
.header_links_ul li{
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border-right:1px solid #000;
}
.header_links_ul li:last-child{
  padding: 0px 20px;
  border-right:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi @max777 add below CSS in you code, that will help you..

```
<style>
  header_links_ul li
  { border-right: 1px solid green;  margin-left: 2%;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the wrong approach for creating header!

Use bootstrap nav bar form the following links:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

And then use `position:relative` on `li` like this

```
.header_links_ul li {
  position: relative;
 }
```

If you need more help Please post Code-pen OR fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header_links_ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header_links_ul li a {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
}
.header_links_ul li{
line-height:15px
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
  .header_links_ul li+li::before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 1px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    background: #ff0000;
    content: '';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="header_links_ul header_links_ul_left d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-start">
      <li><a href="#">Vásárlási információk</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Szállítás</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kapcsolat</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="header_links_ul header_links_ul_right d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end">
      <li><a href="#">Regisztráció</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Bejelentkezés</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```